# Using files (go:embed) with gomigrate package

Tags: go, migration

I want to be able to embed migration files within the output binary.

So that i can get those files as variables then use them to call the migrate functions.

The package I use is github.com/DavidHuie/gomigrate

The code below reads from the folder called `./migrations` which includes a file `1_add_users_table_up.sql` as well as a `_down.sql`.

I want to embed them using `go:embed` and use them directly in the function as a file.

```
func MigrateUp(db *sqlx.DB) error {
    migrator, _ := gomigrate.NewMigrator(db.DB, gomigrate.Postgres{}, "./migrations")

    err := migrator.Migrate()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

### EDIT:

I ended up using the package `github.com/golang-migrate/migrate` instead since it provides embedding the migration files.

Comment: That library is tied to the filesystem (e.g. it uses [`filepath.Glob`](https://github.com/DavidHuie/gomigrate/blob/master/gomigrate.go#L125) to get the migrations) so it's not going to work with `embed.FS` without modifications. I use [migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) with embedded migrations and that works well.

Comment: the best way to communicate with an open source project would be to talk to the maintainers, I opened an issue proposing embed.FS support https://github.com/farseer810/gomigrate/issues/1

Comment: @avelino You raised the issue against a different project (the OP is using `github.com/DavidHuie/gomigrate`). There is already an [open issue](https://github.com/DavidHuie/gomigrate/issues/15) on the project used that would go some way towards adding support for `embed` but as the last commit on the project was in 2019 I doubt changes will be forthcoming.

Comment: How did you use github.com/golang-migrate/migrate? The documentation is poor that using the only example that's there leads to ftrustration because the `.Up()` function works but returns an error stating that there are no changes to be made to the database (everything is up to date). So this is treated an error.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 As with many (all?) open source projects `golang-migrate` has some issues but, overall, I've found it to work well and the docs are better than many projects (you are welcome to raise pull requests to improve this, fork the project, or create something yourself). See [this issue](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/issues/100) re your specific complaint (once a decision is made on how the API should work its difficult to change it as users may rely on the existing functionality). If you have further issues I'd suggest raising them in a new question.

Comment: @Brits Thank you. Thank fixed the issue. They could have actually put that in the documentation instead of making people guess.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using iofs driver from [the example](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/blob/master/source/iofs/example_test.go):

```
import "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/iofs"

//go:embed migrations
var migrations embed.FS

source, err := iofs.New(migrations, "migrations")
m, err := migrate.NewWithInstance("iofs", source, "postgres", db)
```

Comment: I am getting `first migrations: file does not exist` error. Using this method. Although if I print the files using `fs.ReadDir(db.migrationFiles, "migrations")`, it prints the list of files.